# Is it possible to use Dropbox to keep 2 pcs mail programs synced?

Tags: email, sync, dropbox

Is it possible that I use a dropbox folder as the mail storage so that both my pcs have the exactly same "state" as mail program is related? Would dropbox automatically update the folder database / index file of the mail program? I am currently using Windows Live Mail. It stores mail as individual files for each mail but it has a database file that keeps everything organized.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's possible to synchronize all those files in a timely fashion, and the content contains nothing that is specific to each PC you'll have problems with files getting overwritten when they shouldn't, because each mail program stores its own data and doesn't know that another program will store its data in the same file.

For this scenario, IMAP was invented. There the mail server keeps a database of all mails and each mail program has a (partial) copy that is synced with the server. Most mail servers offer IMAP, so just activate that in your mail programs and everything should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox will work, but it is not the best method for this.  Dropbox does not synchronize [open files](https://www.dropbox.com/help/52/en).  Therefore, if your mail application has these files open, they will not sync till the application is closed.

Comment: what about shadow copies?

Comment: is it possible that I make a Task Schedule to close the program and sync dropbox exactly when I send the computer to hibernation?

Comment: Shadow copies can't work, because you want 2-way sync and for that you need to change the original data.